# Cómo segmentar una página en tres partes (oracle apex)

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, apex, oracle-10g, apex-chart

Estoy trabajando en una página de ingreso de datos, pero es muy larga, considero que sería mejor segemntarla en tres partes para una mejor visualización de ese formulario! La versión de oracle apex que estoy utilizando es 4.2.5.

Quisiera que me ayuden en ¿cómo segmentar una página en tres partes en herramienta oracle Apex? 4.2.5.

De antemano gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Puede crear una región tipo Tab o Region Display Selector para agrupar la información de acuerdo al tipo de datos. Algunos ejemplos en [apex.oracle.com/ut](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/apex_pm/r/ut/tabs-and-region-display-selector)

Lastimosamente no tengo un ambiente con APEX 4.2 para enviar un ejemplo mas preciso, considera actualizar a una versión mas reciente.

Comment: Aún así, agradezco mucho que me haya brindado su ayuda, pues me ha dado la pauta para poder hacer lo que necesito.